# How to specify statusCallbackEvent in Twillio Programmable Video statusCallback while creating a room?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video, twilio-node, twilio-javascript

Is there any way to specify the statusCallbackEvent while creating a room using Room API? Like in TwiML we can specify the statusCallbackEvent [docs here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client). Here is the code snippet for room creatiion:

```
        // Create Room using twilio API
        const room = await client.video.rooms.create({
            type: type, //group-small
            uniqueName: req.body.room,
            maxParticipants: maxParticipants,
            recordParticipantsOnConnect: false,
            mediaRegion: "in1",
            statusCallback: process.env.URL+"/room/room-ended",
            statusCallbackMethod: "POST",
            // statusCallbackEvent: ['room-ended'] specifying the room completed event
        });
```

Currently it sends POST request to my backend on every event like 'participant-connected, disconnected...'.

Here is the snippet to handle the POST request

```
// Method: POST
// deletes room from database after a room is completed
// callback after room completed
router.post('/room-ended', async (req, res)=>{

    // Get room model from database and delete it
    if(req.body.RoomStatus === "completed")
        await Room.deleteOne({sid: req.body.RoomSid});

    res.status(200).send("success");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps you have in place are correct: set a statusCallback URL when creating the room, and then use logic to handle the specific events you want to process like 'room-created'.

Unfortunately, specifying one or more events  for the statusCallback Events is not an option.

Rooms Status Callback Events: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks#rooms-callback-events

Reference : https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks